# Terminology: Is $f(x)=5*g(x)$ 'increasing' in $g(x)$?

Tags: functions, terminology

Consider the following function

$$f(x)=5*g(x)$$

Can I say that this function is increasing in $g(x)$, or is the term 'increasing' only used to refer to variables, and not functions? If not, how should this relationship be described?

Comment: I have certainly seen the world "increasing" used for function transformations (I forget the exact context) but it's not common useage.

Comment: We have a natural (partial) order on functions given by $f_1\leq f_2$ if $f_1(x)\leq f_2(x)$ for all $x$, and we could call a transformation $T$ increasing if it preserves the order, i.e. if $f_1\leq f_2$, then $T(f_1)\leq T(f_2)$. With that definition, your operation is indeed increasing. I will let someone else elaborate on that.

Comment: Is this terminology you want to use?  Math terminology is flexible in the sense that you as an author (or speaker) are free to define vocabulary to suit your purpose.  The key is give a definition when (as here) a  possibility for confusion is present.  I'd prefer to say "$f (x)$ is directly proportional to $g(x)$" to describe that particular situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly say that $f$ is *proportional to* $g,$ or write $f\propto g.$ You could also say they are "ordinally equivalent," which seems to be what you're trying to say.

> Two functions $f,g:X\to\Bbb R$ are said to be *ordinally equivalent* if one of the following (equivalent) conditions is satisfied:
>
> - For all $x,y\in X,$ we have $f(x)\le f(y)$ iff $g(x)\le g(y).$
> - There is a strictly increasing function $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f=\phi\circ g.$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function. A function needs a domain and range.

For functions you have the term of (strict) monotonicity.
If your $g$ is (strict) monoton, then your $f$ is (strict) monoton.

You might check this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotonicFunction.html

Comment: What if it's domain is the real numbers?

Comment: Nothing special. I just want to emphasis, that a funtion (by definition) needs a domain and range and should be noted like $f: D\to R$ and $g: D_1\to R_1$ or something else. What the domain and range really is, does not matter that much here. D can be $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}$ or everything else where you have an order relation such like "$\leq$". (Same goes for the range.)

Answer (score 1):

The monotonicity is a property of the function. 
And $f(x)$ is in general a different function than $f(g)$.
I would not use this.